# Is it's a good pracice to give same id's to multiple tags?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

The first thing that comes to my mind when i hear the word **ID** is that it's something which is unique, Well it is in the case of ASP.NET server tags. But it seems that there is nothing wrong using same id's for multiple tags if it's not a server tag. So is it a problem at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your DOM selectors will fail. `document.getElementById` will only return the first match, and different javascript libraries might to their own funky stuff depending on the parsing they do on your selectors. plus, different browsers might also do their own when using `querySelectorAll`.

I'd recommend to use a `class` attribute instead of an `id`, even if you do not intend to address the elements with javascript. Repeating the same `id` on a page is still invalid code and will lead to uncertain results.

Comment: the `name` attribute is only valid on form elements (using the `name` attribute on anchors has been deprecated in HTML5), and you should not abuse it to do either CSS styling or addressing those elements with javascript.

Comment: Agreed, +1 for the very nice explanation of why it's bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

No , you shouldn't reuse the tags even though they are serverside, they add the clientid to the server but again it should be unique.

anyway why do you want to reuse them??

Please see the below code , we can make it unique like this

```
 <li id="userID<%# Eval("UserId")%>">
```

other example

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="idtest" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="catID<%# Eval("Id")%>" class="Content">
                    <ul id="someotherRandom<%# Eval("Id").ToString()%>" style="width:364px;">                    
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: When you place a non server tag inside a Repeater or ListView and give it some id.. this happens..

Comment: a better option would be `<li id="userID<%# Container.ItemIndex %>">` But repeaed ids == no problem means that you would be able to save that extra line of code..

Answer (score 1):

> So is it a problem at all?

It wouldn't validate: the IDs of HTML elements are supposed to be unique. It would be difficult to hyperlink to an element whose ID is not unique.

Comment: So it's upto the requirement.. sometimes you may want to bind a click event to all those elements with same ID(which you still can do even they have _similar_ ids).. Same id == no problem means that you can save two or three lines of code..

Comment: @TheSupertram, if you have the same id ,after somttime your DOM may start responding weird and it gets difficult to debug for you , so its always best practice to have unique ids.

Comment: @TheSuperTramp All versions of the HTML spec say that the ID should be unique within the document; see for example [7.5.2 Element identifiers: the id and class attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

Answer (score 1):

IDs should be unique. If you need to identify a tag that repeats then you need to give it a class. The class attribute is intended to identify multiple items on a page.